# 6-wheeled robot in gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

I'm trying to simulate in gazebo a 6-wheeled robot and I'd like to control each wheel independently. I've tried with skid_steer_controller (but I'm afraid that's only for 4 wheels) and with diff_drive_controller (but the problem is that each pair of wheels works in the same way, and I want ALL the wheels to run independently...)
Is there any other controller useful for my case? Or at least, is there any ros_package of a 6-wheeled robot example(similar for example to [r-hex](http://www.bostondynamics.com/robot_rhex.html) robot ?

I'm using ros indigo

Thanks a lot!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9181/6-wheeled-robot-in-gazebo/) by [ROS_GAZEBO_USER](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1326/ros_gazebo_user/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-08-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I don't know of any gazebo plugin designed for a 6-wheeled vehicle. Fortunately, it's very easy to write your own plugin. You can start by copying the skid steer or diff drive plugin.

There are lots of [tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=plugins), and [examples](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/examples/plugins/).

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-08-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There is a 6 wheel plugin and a generalized multi wheel plugin as parts of [hector_gazebo_plugins](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_gazebo/tree/indigo-devel/hector_gazebo_plugins). Those do not permit actuating the axis independently, but could be modified to do so. Note they are gazebo ROS plugins and not plain gazebo ones.

A usage example is available [here starting in line 130](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/taurob_tracker_common/blob/master/taurob_tracker_description/urdf/tracker_chassis.gazebo.xacro.xml#L130).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 473 on 2015-09-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1